# Web scraping with Python - how to click on date of same value

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to click on the button that contains the text "30 de novembro" but when I use my code it clicks on the "30 de outubro" button
How to fix?

[Screenshot of HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GesCf.png)

Here's the code I'm using

```
selecdia = navegador.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value='30')
selecdia.click()
sleep(1)
```

Comment: Yes, because it checks value '30' and "30 de outubro" comes first, please use other attributes to correctly locate the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the title attribute is the only way to uniquely identify the link you wish to click, therefore in Selenium 4 syntax:

```
selecdia = navegador.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='30 de novembro']")
```

or:

```
selecdia = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@title='30 de novembro']")
```

Comment: It solved my problem, but another one came up. It's just returning me a string, before they returned several. But I don't think that's what caused it.